# How to rewrite static url about flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I was confused in whole day about flask's subdomain.

And the **code** is just like this

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'localhost:5000'
app.url_map.default_subdomain = 'forums'

forums = Blueprint('forums', __name__)


@forums.route('/')
def forums_index():
    print(url_for('static', filename='index.css'))
    return 'forums,hello'

docs = Blueprint('docs', __name__)


@docs.route('/')
def docs_index():
    return 'docs,hello'


app.register_blueprint(forums)
app.register_blueprint(docs, subdomain='docs')


@app.route('/hello')
def index():
    return 'index,hello'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
    print(app.url_map)
```

The all url:

```
Map([<Rule 'forums|/hello' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> index>,
 <Rule 'forums|/' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> forums.forums_index>,
 <Rule 'docs|/' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> docs.docs_index>,
 <Rule '/static/<filename>' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> static>])
```

I visit `forums.localhost:5000`,the print would like this
`http://localhost:5000/static/index.css`

I think I add **default_subdomain**,the print should be
`http://forums.localhost:5000/static/index.css`

Now,I use `url_for('static',filename='index.css')` in  templates.But I can't get css file in Pruduction Environment.

How can I rewrite static url?
I have a look at source of flask. and add

```
app.add_url_rule(app.static_url_path + '/<path:filename>',
                endpoint='static',
                view_func=app.send_static_file,
                subdomain='forums')
```

Unfortunately，it didn't overwrite orginal static url.
So,How to rewrite static url about flask?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a answer here https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1559

just add

```
app.url_map._rules.clear()
app.url_map._rules_by_endpoint.clear()
```

after `app = Flask(__name__)`
Then the all url :

```
Map([<Rule 'forums|/hello' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> index>,
 <Rule 'forums|/' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> forums.forums_index>,
 <Rule 'docs|/' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> docs.docs_index>,
 <Rule 'forums|/static/<filename>' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> static>])
```